# Can I customize data serialization mechanism in spark

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, apache-spark

In my project, I need to ship plenty of existing Java objects to Spark workers, most of them are not extended from `java.io.Serializable`. I also want the ability to control the variables/attributes included in the objects. I only want to serialize the useful attributes, not everything in a object.

Spark documentation indicates that there are two ways to serialize an object in Spark, using `java.io.Serializable` or Kryo.  I think both ways need to rewrite a bunch of wrappers or extra code for every business objects.  However, my current code base has already implemented protocol-buffers serialization. I am wondering if there is any way to embed this serialization mechanism into Spark.